# Django search form, disambiguation page

Tags: python, django

Hello everybody I keep having this problem with my search form in my website. The thing is that, based on the user input, i check if in the database there're some results. But if the input is both in band column and album colum I'd like the user to be redirected to a 'disambiguation' html page. This is my views.py but it doesn't work. Hope someone could help me, thanks!

Views.py

```
class searchesView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "search/searches.html"

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print('FORM POSTED WITH {}'.format(request.POST['srh']))
        srch = request.POST.get('srh')
        if srch:
            sr = Info.objects.filter(Q(band__icontains=srch))
            sd = Info.objects.filter(Q(disco__icontains=srch))

            if sr is sd:
                return render(self.request, 'search/disambigua.html')
            else:
                paginator = Paginator(sr, 10)
                page_number = request.GET.get('page')
                page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)

                return render(self.request, 'search/searches.html', {'sr':sr,
                                                                       'sd': sd,
                                                                       'page_obj': page_obj
                                                                       })

        else:
            return render(self.request, 'search/searches.html')
```

Comment: `if sr is sd` checks if the two python objects `sr` and `sd` are the same. They will never be the same. You probably want to check if they both contain results, i.e. `if sr.exists() and sd.exists()`

Comment: perfect! now it works, thanks a lot. I know this is kinda stupid but Iìm new to Django and Python